# How can I target last li in a menu to not show before hover content?

Tags: html, css

I have a mega menu with an image in the last column of the drop down mega menu. There's a hover stated for the megamenu items and it currently is applying that to the image as well. With it being the last "li a" I was trying to use the following code with no luck:

```
.rd-navbar-static .rd-navbar-megamenu > li  a:last-of-type:before,
.rd-navbar-fullwidth .rd-navbar-megamenu > li  a:last-of-type:before {
    content: none;
 }
```

With that code, it turns off the hover for all the megamenu items. I was thinking I could possibly use nth of type or child, but I'm not super familiar with it.

The sample site/menu is here: https://www.norcomct.com/index-menu-test.htm

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you share your code in this thread as a snippet? It's not safe for us to open links to custom sites. But please let us know about applying `li:last-of-type a:before` instead?

Comment: I think I was heading down the wrong path there, I just applied a class to the a tag for the image and set the content to none and that seems to do the trick. I will try your suggestion as well. Thanks!